# Set custom path prefix in API method using Swagger in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger

I would like add **my custom path prefix** using swagger in .Net Core API methods.

For example, my API methods are declared like this:

```
[Route("api/v1/Customer")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Customer()
{
        // some implementation
        return Ok();
}
```

So currently, If I invoke the API using http://localhost:50523/api/v1/Customer it works perfectly fine.

**Now, I want to add some custom path prefix**. E.g. `/some/custom/path/` before the actual API method path. Which means that-- if I invoke the API using http://localhost:50523/some/custom/path/api/v1/Customer it should work.

**I want to achieve this using Swagger in .Net core, and I do not want to change the API path on action method level** since I have hundred of API method written and I do not want to change the URL on each action method.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to have a look on this link: https://www.strathweb.com/2016/06/global-route-prefix-with-asp-net-core-mvc-revisited/

Answer (score 6):

In .Net 5.0

```
public class PathPrefixInsertDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    private readonly string _pathPrefix;

    public PathPrefixInsertDocumentFilter(string prefix)
    {
        this._pathPrefix = prefix;
    }

    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        var paths = swaggerDoc.Paths.Keys.ToList();
        foreach (var path in paths)
        {
            var pathToChange = swaggerDoc.Paths[path];
            swaggerDoc.Paths.Remove(path);
            swaggerDoc.Paths.Add($"{_pathPrefix}{path}", pathToChange);
        }
    }
}
```

To apply the filter

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info {Title = "MyApp", Version = "v1"});

    ...  other setup

    options.DocumentFilter<PathPrefixInsertDocumentFilter>("api");
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you add a DocumentFilter you can add the prefix to all the paths you want to change.

```
public class PathPrefixInsertDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    private readonly string _pathPrefix;

    public PathPrefixInsertDocumentFilter(string prefix)
    {
        this._pathPrefix = prefix;
    }

    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        var paths = swaggerDoc.Paths.Keys.ToList();
        foreach (var path in paths)
        {
            var pathToChange = swaggerDoc.Paths[path];
            swaggerDoc.Paths.Remove(path);
            swaggerDoc.Paths.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, PathItem>("/" + _pathPrefix + path, pathToChange));
        }
    }
}
```

You then add the filter in your swagger set up:

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info {Title = "MyApp", Version = "v1"});

            ...  other setup

            options.DocumentFilter<PathPrefixInsertDocumentFilter>("api");
        });
```

This doesn't change your API - we use this for working with a reverse proxy in production where we use the prefix to route the request to the appropriate container but strip it out.

Comment: If you don't want to change the path as displayed in the Swagger UI, you can just use a DocumentFilter that simply applies the prefix to the `swaggerDoc.BasePath`. This leaves the endpoint displayed without the prefix in the UI but it gets used when trying to call it.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe You can using Route attribute in your Controller class like:
    
    `[Route("/some/custom/path/")]
    public class CustomerController
    {
       [Route("api/v1/Customer")]
       [HttpGet]
       public async Task<IActionResult> Customer()
       {
        // some implementation
        return Ok();
       }
    }`

Hope it works for you

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot declare this in controller level since my custom path would get change based on environment e.g. production, staging etc.

Answer (score -1):

you can use **`[Route("prefix/[controller]")]`** top of your api controller

```
[Route("prefix/[controller]")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
  [Route("api/v1/Customer")]
  [HttpGet]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Customer()
   {
    // some implementation
    return Ok();
    }
}
```